# How do I disable the add friend button for mutual friends on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-friend-request

I have seen on Facebook that it is explicitly possible for a user who shares mutual friends with another user to somehow disable the ability to become added as a friend. This is regardless of recent blocking or unblockings, or even recent friend requests. and a clearly visible group of mutual friends on their profile. I would like to know how to apply this privacy setting on my Facebook page, so that certain users who I share friends with cannot send me requests.

In Facebook's privacy settings, it seems that I can either set my "Add Friend" possibilities to "Everyone" or "Friends of Friends". How do I make it so some mutual friends cannot add me?

To be clear I do not want to block these people.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, there is only two options "Everyone" or "Friends of Friends". So if you don't want block, you can ignore when they send friend request. They can't add you without your permission. Here ignoring means when someone send you friend request, just delete that request and mark as you don't know that person. In future that person wont be able to sent you friend request from that ID.